# What is known about this generalisation of the derived group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, derived-subgroup

Recently I've been revising a course on Representation Theory. As part of that course, we ended up proving that the intersection of the kernels of all 1D representations of a group is its *derived group*, i.e. the group generated by its collection of commutators.

Let's now say that $G^{(n)}$ is intersection of the kernels of all the group homomorphisms $G\to \text{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ (so the above result tells us $G^{(1)} = \delta(G)$). Is there much known about these $G^{(n)}$?

One quick result is that for any finite group, $G^{(n)}$ is trivial for all sufficiently large $n$. What else can we say?

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group, all subgroups are finite, so I don't see why you need "sufficiently large $n$" there.

Comment: I mean, I guess for some $n$ there are no homomorphisms, but then the natural definition is $G^{(n)}=G,$ not some infinite group.

Comment: The notation $G^{(n)}$ is somewhat misleading: it could be mistaken for the n-th derived subgroup.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry! I meant to say it eventually becomes trivial.